# Does the trinket from the Asari consort have any use in the later games?

Tags: mass-effect-series

According to the [wiki page of Eletania](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Eletania) this carries over to ME2. Does it have any effect in the later games?

Comment: I don't remember a single thing referencing that vision from ME1 in either 2 or 3

Comment: That may have been a sound judgement on the part of the developers. It was common to visit the Consort before talking with the Elcor Diplomat, thus failing to receive the trinket to unlock the Prothean artifact since she only awards it for players who visit her only after both quests are resolved.

Comment: I always received the trinket but did not bother to find where can I use it. :)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Mass Effect Wiki](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Eletania#The_Vision) the event is flagged in save-game imports from ME1->ME2.  However, there is no mention of it *actually* having an effect on either game.

> Finding and unlocking the ruin is flagged as an event when imported into a Mass Effect 2 character, though it is currently not known whether there is any effect in the game. It is possible the import was meant to carry over to Mass Effect 3 through Mass Effect 2.

I personally haven't noticed any follow-up.  I did receive the vision on Eletania, and have played through the entire Trilogy - though I haven't played any DLCs for ME3 yet.

Answer (score 2):

Very outdated I know but there is a planet in ME1 that you can find a prothean rune similar to the one you have in your cabin during ME3 and if you interact with it when using the trinket something happen

Comment: Thanks! I've found it a year ago and it was awesome! I just love this hidden pieces in games like ME.

Answer (score 0):

again from [the wiki](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Citadel:_Asari_Consort#The_Trinket), about the trinket:

> If you completed Citadel: Xeltan's Complaint before coming to her, Sha'ira will give you a bonus reward, a small trinket that appears to be of Prothean design. This can be used on Eletania, a planet in the Hercules system of the Attican Beta cluster. Use the trinket when examining the anomaly at the ruins, and you will experience a short burst of information about the Protheans studying cavemen on Earth. If you do not speak to Xeltan before coming to Sha'ira, her door will be locked and you won't get the trinket.

This item was intended to be carried over in ME2 for a quest that was cut out from the game (source of this: a couple of posts in the bioware forums. yet, I think it's just rumors/voices running around, but it's the answer with the most sense I could find)

Other rumors (unverified, again from the forums) about ME3: it's the key for

> the crucible

or it just gives you a slight increase in your war assets.

Comment: It's definitely *not* the key you suggest.  I'm pretty sure it wasn't a War Asset either, but I didn't really check every single one of those during my play-through to say definitively.

Comment: I know it's not the key for what I said, having finished multiple times the trilogy :) The trinket has no point in ME2 and 3, I listed only early rumors from when ME2 was about to come out :) Your answer is not better than mine :)